# Usage summarise_ and group_by_ in my own function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create a simple function which will use `summarise_` and `group_by_` function. I know that there is a problem with non-standard evaluation but I could fix it.

```
library(dplyr)
test_function <- function(.data, ..., variable){
  dots <- quote(mean(substitute(variable)))
    group_by_(.data,.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    summarise_(.dots = dots)
}
```

But when I try this:

```
test_function(ggplot2::diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price)
```

It does not work.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe because you used the wrong name ;) fix with `test_function` instead of `test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is your `quote()`. The quote is escaping the `substitute()` so it's not running the way you want it to. If you use `bquote()` instead, you can evaulate the substitute and insert the result into the expression to get what you want

```
test_function <- function(.data, ..., variable){
    dots <- bquote(mean(.(substitute(variable))))
    group_by_(.data,.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    summarise_(.dots = dots)
}

test_function(diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price)
# Source: local data frame [40 x 3]
# Groups: cut
# 
#     cut clarity mean(price)
# 1  Fair      I1    3703.533
# 2  Fair     SI2    5173.916
# 3  Fair     SI1    4208.279
# 4  Fair     VS2    4174.724
# 5  Fair     VS1    4165.141
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks I just wonder it is possible to add additional variable `FUN` within function - `function(.data, ..., variable, FUN)` where I can determine which function I want to use. How should I use `bquote` in order to implement it correctly?

Comment: Functions are a bit easier to work with than raw symbol names. You should just be able to do `dots <- bquote(FUN(.(substitute(variable))))` since you don't need to delay evaluation of the function itself.

Comment: OK, yeah, the scoping rules of the standard evaluation `dplyr` functions are a bit tricky. `dots <- eval(bquote(~FUN(.(substitute(variable)))))` seems to work. To go into details about why is outside the scope of this particular questions.

Comment: The help pages? The dplyr non-standard evaluation vignette `vignette("nse", "dplyr")`? Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)?

Comment: Thanks, One more thing, I want to use this function within another function, so: `test_function2 <– function(data, ..., variable, FUN) { test_function(data, ..., variable, FUN) }` and then I want to use this function as previous `test_function2(diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price, FUN - mean)` it doesn't work. I get an error: `ERROR: Could not find object price`.

Comment: This sounds like a different problem. You should consider starting a new post rather than asking new/different questions in the comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754530/nested-dplyr-based-function-within-another-function

Answer (score 0):

Intstead of using complicated phrase `bquote(mean(.(substitute(variable))))` I found `interp` function which simplify notation a bit.

```
...
interp(~mean(variable), variable = substitute(variable))
...
```