# Nested dplyr-based function within another function

Tags: r, dplyr

Thanks to @MrFlick I can handle with the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752889/usage-summarise-and-group-by-in-my-own-function/31752958?noredirect=1#comment51442187_31752958) in usage `dplyr` function within my own function. But another problem came up. After implementing `test_function`:

```
test_function <- function(.data, ..., variable, FUN){
    dots <- eval(bquote(~FUN(.(substitute(variable)))))
    group_by_(.data,.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    summarise_(.dots = dots)
}
```

I wanted to use this function within another function to do sth more:

```
test_function2 <– function(data, ..., variable, FUN) { 
   test_function(data, ..., variable, FUN) 
   # another computation
}
```

and after that I tried:

```
test_function2(diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price, FUN - mean)
```

in a result I got an error : `Error: Could not find object price`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why trying to use non-standard evaluation can be a big mess. The first problem you have is the issue of named parameters and `...` parameters. If you want to use parameters after dots, they *must* be named in the call, for example

```
test_function(data, ..., variable=variable, FUN=FUN)
```

otherwise they would just wind up with everything else in the `...`.

The next problem is that now the parameter you are passing to `variable=` is `variable`. THis means, when `test_function` tries `substitute()`, it just get's back `variable`. R can't tell when you want to resolve the symbol name.  It basically looks the same as

```
test_function(data, ..., variable=price, FUN=mean)
```

One way to deal with this complicated next call is to use `match.call()`. Here we do a bit of extra work because you renamed the data parameter

```
test_function2 <- function(data, ..., variable, FUN) { 
   mc <- match.call()
   mc[[1]] <- quote(test_function)
   mc$.data <- mc$data
   mc$data <- NULL
   eval(mc)
}
```

basically we just take everything that was passed to `test_function2`  and pass it along to `test_function`.

Comment: Wooh! Thanks a lot! Bunch of great stuff. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also just tell `substitute` where it should look for variable, adding this line to `test_function` (plus using `variable=variable` and `FUN=FUN` when passing those arguments)

```
test_function <- function(.data, ..., variable, FUN){
    e <- parent.frame()
    dots <- eval(bquote(~FUN(.(substitute(variable, env=e)))))
    ...
```

Comment: This seems to prevent you from calling `test_function` directly. So `test_function2(diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price, FUN = mean)` will work but `test_function(diamonds, cut, clarity, variable = price, FUN = mean)` will no longer work, or did i miss something?

Comment: @MrFlick yes, that's right, see `?parent.frame`, you would need the variable defined there.  A more general solution could simply pass the appropriate environment.